# Logic low not low enough

Tags: serial, uart, logic-level

I'm having an issue where the "low" level being output from one device isn't low enough for the device on the other end to interpret it as such. I'm guessing I'm not the first person to have this problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Here are the details:

I'm trying to interface between the [ALDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALDL) connector in my car and a [Teensy++ 2.0](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/index.html). ALDL uses a UART-like protocol at 8192 baud, except transmit and receive are on the same wire. The circuit I'm using (from [here](http://lukeskaff.com/?page_id=305)) is below:

[image: ALDL schematic]

When the "Receive Control Pin" (a regular, software-controlled, digital IO pin on the Teensy) is low, the ALDL data line should be able to drive the Teensy's receive line. When it is high, the Teensy's transmit line should be able to drive the ALDL data line while the Teensy receive line is held high.

So far, it hasn't been working. I think the problem is that unless the ALDL data line is brought very close to ground when low, the Teensy's receive line doesn't read it as such. To test this, I disconnected the ALDL line and manually jumpered it to ground. The Teensy's receive line dropped to 0.93V, and it read a byte. Then, I jumpered the ALDL line to 0.45V (from a voltage divider). That time, the Teensy's receive line only went to 1.65V, and it didn't read anything.

The little documentation I found said the ALDL line can output as high as 0.8V when low. Is there any way to modify this circuit or build a different one to avoid this problem?

**Edit:**

The ALDL signals are at a 5V level. Specifically:

**Transmit**
Low level output voltage: 0.8V max
High level output voltage: 4.0V min

**Receive**
Low level input voltage: 2.0V max
High level input voltage: 2.8V min

Comment: What voltage represents a high on the ALDL signalling line?  Wiki says 5 or 12V; what is it in your case?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have added more detail in the first place, but I was worried about the question getting too long. I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will reduce the input voltage to your board by about 0.5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f16mh9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I didn't have any higher than 10k resistors on hand, so I used one of those. The low voltage on RX is now well within range, but the high voltage is also now well below the acceptable range. I'm assuming that's the weaker resistor's fault though. I better order some stronger ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a diode in series with the BJT gates to double the voltage at which the BJT's switch on, from 0.7V to 1.4V.  That should take the operating voltage well above the 0.8V of your ALDL signal.

Ignore me, it's not that; I didn't look at the circuit closely enough.  Adding a series diode is NOT going to fix your problem (but hey, try it anyway...)

See also my follow-up question.

Comment: I apologize for my noobishness--I'm relatively new to electronics--but could you elaborate/explain a bit more? I'm not 100% sure I understand where you mean a diode should go or why that works.

Comment: Is the idea to do something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FioxL.png)?

Comment: The diode should point in the same direction as the arrow in the BJT, i.e. reverse it from that diagram.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I understand why that would help. Though I wouldn't complain about a little more explanation either :)

Comment: Well, I tried it anyway, and it actually made the voltages on RX higher. It actually prevented the Teensy from registering low even when I jumper the ALDL line directly to ground. Thanks, though. Also, I updated my question.